# What does kpsewhere do?

Tags: filesystem, latex

Hello Ubuntu community,

I had a look at this page

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160702/how-do-i-write-documents-using-llncs-cls-without-having-to-put-it-in-the-same-fo

to fix a similar issue I had. From the answer it appears I should launch the command `kpsewhere`. Since I don't know what this command does, I tried

`kpsewhere --help`

but the explanation wasn't really clear to me. I guess it searches for the location of its argument. And what else?

Answer (score 2):

The *`kpsewhere`* is a part of [`texlive-extra-utils` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=kpsewhere&mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&arch=any).

It has a man-page - you can read it locally `man kpsewhere` or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/kpsewhere.1.html) to get preliminary knowledge about it:

> **NAME**
> kpsewhere  -  Expanding  `kpsewhich`  to  separately  iterate over each texmf tree listed in $TEXMF.
>
> …
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
> `kpsewhere` is an extension to `kpsewhich` (as where is for which in tcsh).  The intention  is to  provide  a  way to check for conflicts/shadowed files. It will, however, only find one file per TEXMF tree.